# Where can I find labeled but unsegmented time series datasets?

Tags: time-series

Almost all datasets in the UCR archive contain only time series sequences that are segmented and scaled to the same length, which is unrealistic. Are there any time series datasets that are not segmented but labeled?

Answer (score 1):

The new UCR datasets have a few such examples, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07758

Also, there are three or four such datasets in https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SDM_RealisticTSClassifcation_cameraReady.pdf

eamonn